# Juju openstack charms

Tags: configuration, juju

Openstack charm service settings e.g. "nova-cloud-controller" has options to modify nova.conf through config-flags (string).
How do I update neutron.conf within nova-cloud-controller / quantum-gateway charms ?

Thanks,
Astar

Comment: Thanks Felipe. Here's the bug details https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1391611

Answer (score 0):

I checked charm's code and sadly there is no way to inject configuration keys into neutron.conf.

Let me suggest you to file a bug in launchpad, because it sounds like something that should be supported.

Felipe,